# Is there any way we can identify the insertion/updation of record is happened through UI or not

Tags: apex, trigger, class, before-trigger, business-logic

I have requirement where I have one trigger and its calling handler and in handler i have one method,
I need to run that method if I am updating the record through UI in,i dont want to run trigger or method when someone is updating through dataloader/bulk api/web service calls etc.

any way we can check this. not able to understand how to proceed. trigger.isexecuting is not working as on updating its calling trigger and calling that method from class.

Answer (score 3):

As you are already using Apex, you can make use of [Quiddity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_enum_System_Quiddity.htm). As you can see in the docs, a ENUM value of `VF` will state that the "*Execution event is triggered by a Visualforce page*".

```
System.Request.getCurrent().getQuiddity();
```

You could guard your trigger or method when this returns `VF`, or go the extra mile and create a class to contain acceptable and unacceptable execution events to be checked/reused throughout the codebase.

### Update

I found this [QuiddityGuard.cls](https://github.com/trailheadapps/apex-recipes/blob/f95b07045ec3ab766eaf1e48808ebc35b2ce2272/force-app/main/default/classes/Quiddity%20Recipes/QuiddityGuard.cls) in the [ApexRecipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/apex-recipes) repo in case you wish to understand or see it in action.

Comment: UI isn't always VF any more, of course, and getting the correct sub-set of execution context ("quiddity" - a poor use of the term IMHO) may be fiddly.

Comment: Understood @PhilW, I was going to add `AURA` and `QUICK_ACTION` as acceptable UI entry points but I do feel OP should "go the extra mile" if Quiddity is to be used. IMO, a requirement like this is fiddly within itself and almost guaranteed a headache to maintain going forward (code or permission based solution).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be make a new boolean field, with default value False, when running dml from Apex or code make the value true, That way we can understand the action happened from UI or code.

Something similar is done to bypass validation rules

Comment: but i have many objects,so cant really go with this approach

Comment: But this is the workaround we follow as of now, because technically be it from UI or code both in the end are the very same database transactions logically there's no difference between them. You are trying to differentiate something that's not actually different so the only way is differentiating based on a field value, I will follow the question just in case someone has a better way around

Answer (score 0):

There is no intrinsic difference between creating/updating a record through the Salesforce UI or through some other mechanism (after all, you may have a UI in a mobile solution that itself uses REST API to insert the data etc.). However, in all cases there is a "contextual user", though depending on the implementation this may or may not be different in the different contexts and may or may not be a guest user.

If going the contextual user route, it is best to handle changes in server-side behaviour based on [security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_feature_setup.htm) (e.g. CRUD/FLS permissions or [Custom Permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custom_perms_overview.htm&type=5)). You then should ensure that all integration and data loading is performed against contextual users that have the correct setup to avoid your logic being executed.