# How to check record is updated in Classic or Lightning Mode?

Tags: apex, before-trigger

I am trying to find some solution for records updates through UI. As per standard SF behavior if we update the Account Owner all the Open Opportunity Owner is also updated. I want to prevent this behavior but only for the Owner changed from UI. I have tried with various things:

```apex
String requestURL = System.URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().toExternalForm();
If (requestURL.contains('aura.RecordUi.updateRecord=1')
//Check if record is updated from Lightning UI
```

But this is also not working. Because on Owner change the lightning URL is not coming. It is coming as  `https://***.salesforce.com/recordId/a?isdtp=p1`

Can you guys suggest anything else

Comment: Then why can't you use "https://***.salesforce.com/recordId/a?isdtp=p1" for your if condition? wouldn't that work?

Comment: Have you considered [Quiddity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Request.htm#apex_System_Request_getQuiddity)?

Comment: @Phil Quiddity didn't work for me. It always returns SYNCHRONOUS all time. And I need to execute only when it is updated through UI

Comment: @CommonCoreTawan I am not sure if I update through the Apex or Trigger then also I will get the isdtp=p1 or not

Comment: Have you tried using the `getUiThemeDisplayed` method in [UserInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm)?

Comment: @TSmith getUiThemeDisplayed will give me the Classic or Lightning. But how to identify that the Owner is changed from UI or Backend

Comment: " am not sure if I update through the Apex or Trigger then also I will get the isdtp=p1 or not" -- You will have to test it out, maybe it wont.

Comment: think of it from a different angle - who actually updates Account owner through the backend? Is it an integration user? Or are users using dataloader, workbench, etc individually?

Comment: As per what @KrisGoncalves mentioned, see this previous [Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/365651/is-there-any-way-we-can-identify-the-insertion-updation-of-record-is-happened-th/365656#365656).